# Swiping up and down through floor plans

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to implement floor plans in my application, which when swiped will go up or down to the image of the next floor depending on direction, I am unsure how to properly work this in, if anyone could help please?

Comment: Can you attach some screenshots or sketch your idea? It isn't really clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a vertical `RecyclerView` with a [`PagerSnapHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PagerSnapHelper) to simulate a `ViewPager` functionality. A simple example would be:

```
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
    new PagerSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```